# Google Cloud project environment variable not set using Java snippet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, environment-variables, processbuilder

I am trying to set up the environment variable for a Google Cloud project. I'm doing it in right way.
But,

Issue:

Program runs without any error but the environment variable does not set after execution of program.

Code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("export GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=elysiot-217606");
Map<String, String> envMap = pb.environment();
Set<String> keys = envMap.keySet();
for(String key:keys){
    System.out.println(key+" ==> "+envMap.get(key));
}
```